# grep for particular pattern from a list of files and exclude others

Tags: shell

```
new_aged_01
new_aged_01_b
new_aged_01.bak
new_aged_02
new_aged_02_b
new_aged_02.bak
new_aged_03
new_aged_03_b
new_aged_03.bak
```

I have a list of files given above, like to use grep to give me output like below,

```
new_aged_01
new_aged_02
new_aged_03
```

I tried grep , but it did not work

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do let us know if these are the text from a file? Or these are the file names which you want to look for specific file names?

Comment: If those are files in a directory, you don't need grep... `printf "%s\n" new_aged_[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, these are files

Comment: @Shawn, thanks shawn, ur command worked, i also used following grep command to get the same result.

ls |grep "new_aged_[0-9][0-9]$"

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @anandanramar Is my answer the solution you were looking for? If yes could you please validate it?

Answer (score 1):

Using simple regular expression (regex):

`grep -E '^new_aged_\d+$'`

See result on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EOcEVV/1)